# Is this a valid reason to choose a specific sub-field?

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-process, statement-of-purpose, engineering, electrical-engineering

My local university has announced the need for local experts in a specific sub-field within Electrical Engineering (EE), which is why they are offering the opportunity to sponsor student(s) in said sub-field on their master's and PhD studies and providing future job in the university.

I would like to know If I should mention that in my SOP as the reason why I would like to peruse my degree in that particular subject, or should I avoid it at all and simply go with the more generic approach of having interest in it ( which is true considering it is still a sub-field within EE but not necessary the major reason of my choice).

My only worry is that the honesty of my reasons would deter admission referees from taking my application seriously.

Comment: (Comment instead of an answer since I have no experience on admissions comittees.)  To my ear, if you give the impression that this is the *main* reason for your interest, that sounds a bit bad.  But if you say that this was one of the sub-fields you were interested in anyway, and the need for local experts was an extra postive factor on top of that — that sounds fine.

Comment: If you are legitimately interested in the sub-field, then you should be using your SoP to make the case for why _you_ are most qualified for one of the spots in the program; anything else is fluff.

Comment: If your honesty would lessen your chances of admission, then you're not a good fit for the program. **Do not lie in your application.**

Comment: Presumably the reason they're doing this is to attract some/more/better applicants.  So I imagine they expect this to be a reason people will apply.